# Clicking links in Selenium WebDriver and Python: nothing happens

Tags: python

Trying to click the link that says this in the source code

```
<a id="LeaderBoard1_cmdCSV" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;LeaderBoard1$cmdCSV&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Export Data</a></div>
```

I have tried locating by id and link text and get nothing. Any help would be awesome.

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/tmp')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',     'text/csv')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get("http://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?  pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=y&type=c,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,21,22,23,39,41,50&season=2015&month=1&season1=2002&ind=0&team=0&rost=1&age=0&filter=&players=0")

WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

browser.find_element_by_id("LeaderBoard1_cmdCSV").send_keys("\n")`
```

Comment: Please include the related Python code to the question

Comment: I think more importantly you should first confirm that your call to find_element_by_id() is actually finding the appropriate element. Then you can consider what is supposed to happen ("getting nothing" isn't a great explanation)....

Comment: i used selenium IDE to make sure i was finding the right element and it is, so that is not the problem. thanks for your "input"!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to simulate a click or "enter key" press on the anchor tag, you'd be better off using .click() or .sendKeys(Keys.Enter)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```